# How to acces sorted, paged and filtered data from a UIGrid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I want to access all the currently filtered and sorted rows even if they are hidden in different pages.

The line below works as long as I'm not using pagination

```
$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid)
```

And I can access all the rows using the following lines but in this case, the rows are not sorted correctly.

```
var myRows = [];
angular.forEach($scope.gridApi.grid.rows,function(v,k){
    if(v.visible)
        myRows.push(v);
});
```

Is there a simple enough solution to do this?